# why non-const ptr can not implicitly cast to ptr to const as a parameter in template

Tags: c++

i just try to implement std::auto_ptr,my declaration is below.

```
template<typename T>
class auto_ptr_imp
{
public:
   explicit auto_ptr_imp<T>(T const* rhs=NULL);
   auto_ptr_imp(auto_ptr_imp<T>&);
   auto_ptr_imp& operator =(auto_ptr_imp<T>&);
   T& operator*();
   T* operator->();
private:
   T* m_ptr;
};
template<typename T>
auto_ptr_imp<T>::auto_ptr_imp(T * ptr)
  {
    this->m_ptr=ptr;
  }

//in main function call this 
 auto_ptr_imp<ClassA>ptr(new ClassA(2)); //compile error
 int*p=NULL;
 int const* pp=p;//no error
```

then error: “=”: can not cast “const ClassA *”to“ClassA *”.

but i remember when assign a non-const pointer to a pointer to const ,implicit cast will happen. the code below complie well.this makes me confused.

Comment: I don't get that error from the code you've posted, even after fixing the syntax errors. Presumably, your constructor implementation (which you forgot to show us) is trying to initialise `m_ptr` from `rhs`, which won't work because that requires removing a `const` qualifier. But without seeing the code that actually causes the error, I can only guess.

Comment: `auto_ptr_imp` is not defined to be a class template!

Comment: @MikeSeymour  thanks your warn.As you say, error actually happened when i assign m_ptr from rhs.

Comment: When asking about something that fails to compile make sure to include the line of code that *actually fails* as well as the error code. You are doing no one a favor by hiding both the error message and where it happens.

Comment: The parameter type of the declaration `explicit auto_ptr_imp<T>(T const* rhs=NULL);`  does not match the definition. You get -1 for not posting the actual code and the actual error it produces.

Comment: There is no such thing as an implicit cast. A **cast** is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a **conversion**. The issue here is that there is no **implicit conversion** that the compiler can apply.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you meant to declare this:

```
explicit auto_ptr_imp<T>(T const* rhs=NULL);
```

As this:

```
explicit auto_ptr_imp<T>(T * const rhs=NULL);
```

Bear in mind that `const T*` and `T const*` are the same - a non-const pointer to `const T`. Only `T * const` is a const pointer to a non-const `T`.

Comment: I assume no one should want to declare the second signature, since the top level const-volatile qualifier is dropped from the signature and that constructor declaration will effectively be `explicit auto_ptr_imp(T * rhs = NULL)` (except that inside the body of the destructor --but not for callers-- the parameter cannot be modified.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Well, I for one tend to declare parameters as `const` in function definitions if I don't intend to modify them, to catch potential bugs (such as accidentally using the parameter instead of a data member). But I agree it's not common. Still, seemed the most likely explanation here, especially given how the OP differentiates between "non-const pointer" and "pointer to const."

Comment: :) The comparison in `main` with `int const * pp = p; // No error` looks to me like that he really wants to have a non-const pointer to a const object. But then again the fact he ran into that issue indicates that `const` is not so clear for him

Answer (score 0):

If you could assign a value of type "pointer to `const` object" to a pointer to non-`const` object, then you could modify the `const` object through that pointer. Of course that's erroneous.

However, if you assign a pointer to non-`const` object to a pointer to `const` object, then you are just making a promise that *despite the object being modifiable,* you won't modify it. Mutation is not obligatory, so this is fine.